# References appear twice in table of content

Tags: reference, latex, tableofcontents

I have several chapters and I've included a reference section after each chapter using the following command:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\input{References/refdoc.tex}
\end{thebibliography}
```

When I call the \tableofcontents* command, it generates two references section for each and every chapter, any idea why pls?

Thanks a lot :)

[image: TOC snippet showing the two references]

Comment: Can you make a [mre] and also show us the content of `refdoc.tex`?

Comment: Hey thanks for answering. Sure, so refdoc.tex would be something like this

\begin{thebibliography}{9}

\bibitem{maghazei2017implementation} O. Maghazei and T. Netland, "Implementation of industry 4.0 technologies: what can we learn from the past?", IFIP International Conference on Advances in Production Management Systems, pp. 135-142, 2017.

\bibitem{mckinsey2016industry} D. McKinsey, "Industry 4.0 after the initial hype", Where manufacturers are finding value and how they can best capture it, 2016. 

\end{thebibliography}

Comment: These are the packages i'm using ... 

\usepackage{makeidx}         
\usepackage{graphicx}        
\usepackage{multicol}      
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{newtxtext}    
\usepackage{newtxmath}       
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup{compatibility=false}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{booktabs}

Comment: Thanks for sharing this information, but could you please edit your question and add the code there? This way linebreaks etc, will be preserved. Please also make sure that the code has everything necessary to compile, e.g. a documentclass etc